# Cannot get mapper or reducer stack trace with Java agent

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, javaagents

I'm having a problem with profiling JVM for hadoop using Java agent as in https://github.com/etsy/statsd-jvm-profiler

The agent gets stack traces using management API at runtime. The -javaagent argument is specified in the mapred-site.xml file as follows:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx1536m -javaagent:myagent</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx3072m -javaagent:myagent</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

However, my agent cannot get any stack trace for the map or reduce tasks I defined when running my MapReduce application.

Answer (score -1):

For profiling jvm one has multiple options

- enable hadoop default profiling
- run jstat, jmap while the mappers and reducers are running to know about jvm heap usage